# How to handle many images in Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.4, article-manager, media-manager

I have a blog on Joomla 3.4.3 and every day I generate aprox. 15+ articles. Some of them contain many images.

My question is; when I add a new article in Joomla, I have to add its intro image and full article image from *Images and links* tab. And then I have to browse and upload image, then scroll to find the image then click on insert. It is really painful to scroll and find the image so that I can select and insert it, as there aren't any ascending or descending feature or sorting feature. If we talk about K2 then we just have to browse image and add.

Is there any easier way to insert images? I upload more then 50 images in different articles and it's hard to scroll and locate a particular image to add as intro and full image.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem months ago. After installing a site for a new client, with more than 1000 image to upload, I implement this action:

- Create a folder for each month 2015-08, 2015-09, 2015-10...(Its more fast look images in same month)
- Install [JCE Editor](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jce) with [Media Manager](https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/downloads/plugins/media-manager)

With this Editor and this plugin you can upload unlimited images at same time. This plugin can also resize the images like 1000px width in same upload time.

In the last version of JCE Editor, the Joomla image browser has been overridden by a Smart interface from JCE:

[image]

Comment: I have JCE editor but when it comes to adding Intro image and Full image it is really painful.

Comment: You update for last JCE Editor version? In last edition the JCE override Joomla Media Manager. I cant post a image in comment, I will edit my answer.

Comment: oh its premium :/ I dont have money to buy :/ is there any free alternative?

Comment: Yes I have latest JCE 2.5.6 version but I don't see new interface when I browser image from Image and Links tabs. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need this plugin: https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/downloads/plugins/media-manager

Comment: Oh I see, its premium plugin :/ And I dont have money to buy nor any paypal account or card :/

Comment: Max: Any free plugin instead of JCE Media Manager? (As JCE is premium)

Comment: I dont know other. Sorry. After star using this im stop search. This solve all my needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28880/discussion-between-naeem-and-max).